# htaccess mod-rewrite redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect all posts from: https://domain_name/featured-post/*

to: https://domain_name/blog/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?featured-post(.*)$ /blog$1 [R,QSA,L]
```

if the url pattern starts with `/featured-post{any_characters}`, rewrites and redirects to `/blog{any_characters}`.